# Select and change input value in table using data-attribute and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with input fields, and I would like to fill this fields with some data, that users can change if they like.

```js
//Server side processing gives me an array like:
var data = [];
data.push({"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5});
data.push({"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10});

//The data array may not have data for all the rows, and the order of items may not be the same.

//For each data item, I select the appropriate row:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var myRow = $('[data-calcname="' + data.calcname + '"]')[0];
  //And now, try to select the input in each row, but I can't get it to work..:
  //var myInput = myRow.find("input:text")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-calcname="calc1">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-calcname="calc2">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, I have trouble selecting the various input fields, in order to fill them out, as shown in the snippet.

I guess there is an easy jQuery syntax to do this, but despite my best efforts, I have not been able to find it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in a cleaner way, iterate over the `data` array with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and execute a provided function once for each array `el` element.

The rest is jQuery.

Code:

```js
//Server side processing gives me an array like:
var data = [];
data.push({"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5});
data.push({"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10});

data.forEach(function(el) {
  $('tr[data-calcname="' + el.calcname + '"]').find('input:text').val(el.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-calcname="calc1">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-calcname="calc2">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//Server side processing gives me an array like:
var data = [];
data.push({"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5});
data.push({"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10});

//The data array may not have data for all the rows, and the order of items may not be the same.

//For each data item, I select the appropriate row:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var myRow = $('[data-calcname="' + data[i].calcname + '"]').find("input").val(data[i].value);
  //And now, try to select the input in each row, but I can't get it to work..:
  //var myInput = myRow.find("input:text")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-calcname="calc1">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-calcname="calc2">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

1. Use attribute selector to select the td. By combining with `data[i].calcname` to get the desired, with `.find()` to get the input.
2. Set the value using `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to write you selector of the `tr` like this `var myRow = $('tr[data-calcname="' + data[i].calcname + '"]')`

In your case `data[i]` would be: 
`data[0]` = (`{"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5}`) 
 `data[1]` = (`{"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10}`)

```js
//Server side processing gives me an array like:
var data = [];
data.push({"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5});
data.push({"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10});

//The data array may not have data for all the rows, and the order of items may not be the same.

//For each data item, I select the appropriate row:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var myRow = $('tr[data-calcname="' + data[i].calcname + '"]');
  var myInput = myRow.find("input:text").val(data[i].value);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-calcname="calc1">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-calcname="calc2">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `data` is an array i.e. `data[i]`, use index to access the elements, also there is no need use `[0]` which returns the reference to DOM element.

```js
var data = [];
data.push({"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5});
data.push({"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10});

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var myRow = $('[data-calcname="' + data[i].calcname + '"]');
  var myInput = myRow.find("input:text");
  myInput.val(data[i].value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr data-calcname="calc1">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr data-calcname="calc2">
    <td>
      SomeName
    </td>
    <td>
      SomeDescription
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You set up a for loop correctly but now you need to use your index `i` to access the desired element in your array `data`: `data[i].calcname`
2. You don't need to get the row but you need to get the input inside that row: `$('[data-calcname="' + data[i].calcname + '"] td input')`
3. You change a textfield's title by setting its value property: `myInput.value = "new value"`

```js
//Server side processing gives me an array like:
var data = [];
data.push({"calcname" : "calc1", "value" : 5});
data.push({"calcname" : "calc2", "value" : 10});

//The data array may not have data for all the rows, and the order of items may not be the same.

//For each data item, I select the appropriate row:
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var myInput = $('[data-calcname="' + data[i].calcname + '"] td input')[0];
  myInput.value = data[i].value
}
```

### The `for of` loop

If you don't understand step 1. Maybe it is simpler to use the for of loop:

```
for (let element of data) {
  var myInput = $('[data-calcname="' + element.calcname + '"] td input')[0];
  myInput.value = element.value
}
```